# How to delete a row from a table in SQLite android by query statement?

Tags: android, sqlite

My code is not executing delete operation on button click.

```
Button delete_user= (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_user);

    delete_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {


            SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name='name.getText()';");

        }
    });
```

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db;
        db.delete("TableName", "name=?", new String[]{name.getText()});

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct your syntax:

```
SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name='" + name.getText().toString() + "'")
```

Comment: `public void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)`
*Added in API level 1
Execute a single SQL statement that **is NOT** a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/ **DELETE.***

Comment: @downvoter: mindo to explain your behaviour? This answer is correct. AND accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
"DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name='"+name.getText().toString()+"';"
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation why this will work and how and not just paste some code

Answer (score -1):

Java send text expression in quotes. In your case expression:

> DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name='name.getText()';

Change your code like this:

```
 SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name=\'" + name.getText().toString() + "\';");
```