# How to update a row from a table in SQLite android by SQL command?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My code that is not working update operation on `Button` click.

```
 Button update_user= (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_user)
 update_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE mytable  SET name = "+name1_updated.getText() +"
                        WHERE name=name1.getText()+  );


            }
        });
```

please help.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177080/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-table-in-sqlite-android-by-query-statement

Comment: error is:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: m12 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE mytable SET name = m12 WHERE name = n12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to `delete` operation in `Sqlite` than , you have to use these `query` for it

```
 db.execSQL("delete from "+YOUR_TABLE_NAME+" where YOUR_COLUMN_NAME='"+VALUE_BY_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE+"'");
```

And for the `Update` operation. Use these following `query`

```
SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE mytable  SET name = '"+name1_updated.getText() +"' WHERE name='"name1.getText()"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes in where clause

```
SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE mytable  SET name = '"+name1_updated.getText() +"' WHERE name='"name1.getText()"'";
```

When it runs(eg):

```
UPDATE mytable  SET name = 'psypher' WHERE name='neeraj';
```

Another way to do it:

```
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", "psyhper");
    getWritableDatabase().update("mytable", contentValues, "name" + "=?", new String[]{<put whatever name>});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use rawQuery method

```
SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE mytable  SET name = '"+name1_updated.getText() + "'" + "WHERE name= "+"'"name1.getText() +"'"  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct SQL statement is:

```
"UPDATE mytable SET name = " + name1_updated.getText() + " WHERE name = " + name1.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

For update operation make sure you have some appropriate constraint in your table, such as PRIMARY KEY. "insertWithOnConflict" method will do insert/update operation.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("name", "Dhruv");
mDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues , SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

At last my code is working 
and that is:

```
Button update_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_user);
   update_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override`
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SignIn_Signup.sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE mytable  SET name = '"+name1_updated.getText() +"' WHERE name='"+name1.getText()+"'");
        }
    });
```